# Can I decorate a property getter for a single instance only?

Tags: python

I want to give one `dude` an item that changes the way it's attack works. I'd like to somehow wrap the `dmg` function and modify its return value for a single `Dude` instance.

I realized if I decorate `AttackComponent.dmg.fget`, it will affect all instances; when I only want it to affect the one using the item.

`bonus_dmg` changes frequently from buffs/items/etc.

```
class Dude:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = AttackComponent(self)
        self.base_dmg = 9000
        self.bonus_dmg = [9, 90, 900] 
    @property
    def total_dmg(self):
        return self.base_dmg + sum(self.bonus_dmg)

class AttackComponent:
    def __init__(self, dude):
        self.dude = dude
    @property
    def dmg(self):
        return {'physical dmg': self.dude.total_dmg}

dude1 = Dude()
dude2 = Dude()
dude3 = Dude()
```

I want to give `dude1` an item that can modify the return of `dude1.attack.dmg`.
For example it converts a percent of the dmg to magic dmg, such as:

```
print(dude1.attack.dmg)    # {'physical dmg': 7777, 'magic dmg': 2222}
print(dude2.attack.dmg)    # {'physical dmg': 9999}
print(dude3.attack.dmg)    # {'physical dmg': 9999}
```

Comment: Can you just test to see if an instance has the object and modify its return value if it has it?

Comment: Yeah, maybe `Dude` should have a list of items, and `dmg` checks items in its calculations

Comment: Why is `AttackComponent` a separate class?

Comment: I'm trying my best to follow things like SOLID principles, keeping classes small, focused on one thing, decoupled and well organized. It seems like putting the items' logic in `dmg`  it goes against those principles, doesn't it? Maybe I'll do it that way, but I'm curious what you think.

I guess basically my thoughts are that the logic should only go in the item class.

Comment: My goal with the project is to kind of replicate the combat for a MOBA game (league), so lots of moving parts, for what that's worth.